# Como realizar requisição assíncrona usando JSON?

Tags: json, ios, objective-c, assincronismo, request

Cenário, possuo uma requisição de dados usando JSON mas gostaria que essa requisição fosse realizada fora da main thread do app, para que ele não trave e que o usuário possa realizar outras operações enquanto os dados são baixados.

No código abaixo eu já consigo baixar os dados normalmente, porém preciso somente que seja realizado em uma thread secundária.

```
-(void)recebeTodosOsDadosPorFuncionarioDoWebService{        
    NSMutableString* strURL =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/advphp/ArquivosFuncionando/pegaDadosNaoLidosPorFuncionario.php?funcionario=%@",funcionarioCadastrado];           
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: strURL];        
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];        
    NSError*erro;

    arraySalvaDadosProcessos = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&erro];

    if(arraySalvaDados == (id)[NSNull null]|| [arraySalvaDados count] == 0){

       NSLog(@"Erro para receber dados do webservice: \n\n%@", arraySalvaDados);

    }else{

        [self salvaTodosOsDadosRecebidosNoBancoLocal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de executar código em background é usando Grand Central Dispatch (GDC). 
O método dispatch_async executa um block de código assincronamente e retorna imediatamente, isto é, não bloqueia a execução no fluxo atual. 
Você pode criar suas próprias *dispatch queues* ou usar as definidas por padrão.

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  //realize aqui o trabalho em background
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
       //quando as operações em background forem concluídas, execute aqui o código na thread principal para atualização da tela, caso necessário
        });
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelLeão Vou testar aqui o código que me passou e retorno com a resposta!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Agora me explica uma coisa, quando o app é encerrado, este processo é encerrado junto, ou ele vira um processo zumbi?

Comment: Quando o app é encerrado todas suas threads também são.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez @RafaelLeão

Answer (score 3):

Define sua classe como delegate de `<NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>`

Fazendo a requisição:

```
-(void)performRequest{  
    NSString * urlConnection = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                @"Linkaqui"];
    urlConnection = [urlConnection stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: urlConnection];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                      cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval: 4000];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}
```

Pegando a resposta e concatenando em sua `receivedResponse` do tipo `NSData` declarado em suas propriedades da classe:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [receivedResponse appendData: data];
}
```

Capturando algum erro, caso ocorra:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"-----> Error %@ <-----", error);
}
```

Quando terminar de receber todos os dados:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSError       * error     = nil;
    if (receivedResponse != nil && !error) {
        //Chamada assincrona para a manipulação dos dados que obteve com a resposta
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self updatingBackground];
        });
    }else{

    }
}

-(void) updatingBackground{
     //Salva todos os dados que receber/mostra, enfim faz todas as operações
}
```

Comment: apontei a solução do @RafaelLeão como a correta por que ela é prática, mas a tua também é viável e boa! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @TiagoAmaral sem problemas, por melhor prática de programação é você utilizar uma classe `delegate` para efetuar as requisições e obter as respostas. A não ser que seu caso seja algo bem específico em algum local do seu projeto.